I tried to swap a token back to solana in Phantom and it said that the transaction failed now my tokens are in a different wallet
So i bought a token today and wanted to swap it with solana, so i tried to but the transaction failed because there was not enough solana in my account for gas fees. I then check my wallet and all the money is gone. I find out that they have sent it in a completely different wallet. I have the transactions and everything what do i do?
